# pattern not matched fluentd elasticsearch

Tags: regex, elasticsearch, fluentd

I am stucking with writting format of logs in fluentd for magento exception logs.

single exception of **exception.log**

```
[2016-04-30 11:37:42] main.CRITICAL: exception 'Exception' with message 'Report ID: webapi-571f53065307a; Message: Notice: Array to string conversion in /var/www/html/magento2/vendor/monolog/monolog/src/Monolog/Logger.php on line 277' in /var/www/html/magento2/vendor/magento/framework/Webapi/ErrorProcessor.php:194
Stack trace:
#0 /var/www/html/magento2/vendor/magento/framework/Webapi/ErrorProcessor.php(139): Magento\Framework\Webapi\ErrorProcessor->_critical(Object(Exception))
#1 /var/www/html/magento2/vendor/magento/module-webapi/Controller/Rest.php(163): Magento\Framework\Webapi\ErrorProcessor->maskException(Object(Exception))
#2 /var/www/html/magento2/var/generation/Magento/Webapi/Controller/Rest/Interceptor.php(24): Magento\Webapi\Controller\Rest->dispatch(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#3 /var/www/html/magento2/vendor/magento/framework/App/Http.php(115): Magento\Webapi\Controller\Rest\Interceptor->dispatch(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#4 /var/www/html/magento2/vendor/magento/framework/App/Bootstrap.php(258): Magento\Framework\App\Http->launch()
#5 /var/www/html/magento2/index.php(39): Magento\Framework\App\Bootstrap->run(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Http))
#6 {main} [] []
```

**note:** totally 9 lines there (but total number of lines vary as per exception)

my regex pattern of exception log format is

```
/^\[(?<Time>[^ ]* [^ ]*)\] (?<Level>[^ ]*): (?<Exception>.*\n.*):(?<StackTrace>.*\n)$/
```

but its not working, what is the right pattern too collect exception log.

**note:** I have check with http://fluentular.herokuapp.com/ but it did not throw any error.

I expect the output should be look like below

```
Time:[2016-04-30 11:37:42]

Level:main.CRITICAL

Exception:exception 'Exception' with message 'Report ID: webapi-571f53065307a; Message: Notice: Array to string conversion in /var/www/html/magento2/vendor/monolog/monolog/src/Monolog/Logger.php on line 277' in /var/www/html/magento2/vendor/magento/framework/Webapi/ErrorProcessor.php:194

StackTrace:#0 /var/www/html/magento2/vendor/magento/framework/Webapi/ErrorProcessor.php(139): Magento\Framework\Webapi\ErrorProcessor->_critical(Object(Exception))
#1 /var/www/html/magento2/vendor/magento/module-webapi/Controller/Rest.php(163): Magento\Framework\Webapi\ErrorProcessor->maskException(Object(Exception))
#2 /var/www/html/magento2/var/generation/Magento/Webapi/Controller/Rest/Interceptor.php(24): Magento\Webapi\Controller\Rest->dispatch(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#3 /var/www/html/magento2/vendor/magento/framework/App/Http.php(115): Magento\Webapi\Controller\Rest\Interceptor->dispatch(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#4 /var/www/html/magento2/vendor/magento/framework/App/Bootstrap.php(258): Magento\Framework\App\Http->launch()
#5 /var/www/html/magento2/index.php(39): Magento\Framework\App\Bootstrap->run(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Http))
#6 {main} [] []
```

Thanks

Comment: What do you want in output?

Comment: i don't know about fluentd but **[`check`](https://regex101.com/r/cB7sS3/1)**

Comment: If you still have a problem, please add your fluentd configuration in the question.

Answer (score 0):

You are using character class`[]` and unnecessary `$`. I modified a bit of your regex and it works

```
(?<Time>[^ ]* [^ ]*)\ (?<Level>[^ ]*): (?<Exception>[^\n]+)\n*(?<StackTrace>Stack trace:)
```

**[Regex Demo](https://regex101.com/r/yU9jO5/2)**

This regex can also help you

```
(\[[^]]+\])\s+([^:]+):\s+([^\n]+)\n*(Stack trace:)\n
```

**[Regex Demo](https://regex101.com/r/cB7sS3/4)**

Comment: @BilalUsean Just take note that the regex I modified is quite inefficient in case of failure